# Does the .NET browser-wasm runtime have a virtual file system?

Tags: .net, filesystems, browser-wasm

The new (non-Blazor) `browser-wasm` runtime of .NET 7 allows for .NET projects to be compiled to WebAssembly and run in the browser. There is [limited documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/dotnet-interop?view=aspnetcore-7.0) for this, but a lot of the details are still either undocumented or hard to find.

If you were compiling an app to WASM using Emscripten then you would have a virtual file system, to which you could preload files. Does the `browser-wasm` runtime have something similar, that would allow preloading files for the normal .NET file API (like `IO.FileStream`) to access?

There may also be a way to embed files into the WASM file. While no doubt useful for some apps, I need a way to dynamically load/read data files that aren't static data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't been able to find any documentation on this topic.
.NET 7 on WebAssembly uses the Emscripten file system (MEMFS).
To embed assets into the file system, you can use `DotnetHostBuilder.withConfig`. You can access the Emscripten Filesystem API after creating the .NET Runtime.

Here's how you could embed a picture, create a directory, and access file info about the picture from JS:

```js
import { dotnet } from './dotnet.js'
  
const runtime = await dotnet
  .withConfig({
      assets: [
        {
            "virtualPath": "logo.png",
            "behavior": "vfs",
            "name": "logo.png"
        },
    ]
  })
  .create();

const fs = runtime.Module.FS;

fs.mkdir('/new_directory');

const logoInfo = fs.analyzePath('/logo.png');
if (logoInfo.exists) {
  // Logo was loaded into FS.
}

let exit_code = await runtime.runMainAndExit(runtime.getConfig().mainAssemblyName, []);
```

Emscripten API Docs:
https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html

dotnet.js ts Definition:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/mono/wasm/runtime/dotnet.d.ts

Comment: Thank you! Looks like I can pass a buffer into the assets which suits my needs.